# Viewgroup draw not called again after background manipulation

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw, viewgroup

I have a custom `ViewGroup` that overrides `draw()` to draw some stuff over its children. It calls `setWillNotDraw(false)` on the constructor appropriately, and under normal conditions, works as intended.

My problems start when, in the layout XML, on such view I assign a background drawable ("splash screen") and later on in the application I remove this background (`setBackgroundDrawable(null)`). This happens only once, while application is initializing.

```
 <com.regaliz.gui.layouts.FunqRootLayout xmlns:android="..."
    .
android:background="@drawable/a_filmnew_cover_play_splash">
```

From that point, `onDraw` / `draw` is never called again whenever I invalidate the `ViewGroup`.

I've checked the `View.java`'s `setBackgroundDrawable` source code and saw a lot of logic to manipulate the View Flags to add or remove WillNotDraw-related internal flags (but all the methods are private). I suspect this is what's happening: The call to `setBackgroundDrawable(null)` sets the willNotDraw flag), however I am not able to enable it again.

Subsequent calls to

```
 setWillNotDraw(false)
```

are ignored.

To make things funnier, if I don't assign any background in the XML, the setBackgroundDrawable(null) call doesn't seem to touch the flags, so I don't have this problem.

What can be happening?

This is the splash drawable:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:src="@drawable/a_filmnew_cover_play" />
```

Comment: tried using dispatchDraw?

Comment: hmm you have a point... lemme check!

Comment: arghh it works! I think this is an Android bug. Do you think there'd be any performance penalty for overriding dispatchDraw? It should be the same than draw() wont it? if you provide this as answer i'll accept it.

Comment: dispatchDraw calls other draw related methods so it is a mother of all drawing stuff

Comment: yes.. i'm a little worried if I'll be extra-invalidating stuff, I'm just rendering a couple blinking lines over a ton children Views

Comment: if you are not blinking too often, it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try overriding dispatchDraw(Canvas) method